# how to make socat ignore client certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle, socat

I'm trying to set up a listener to check if an application checks the server's certificate (I'm strongly assuming it is not). So I've created a self-signed certificate `fake.pem` for a listener and am trying to connect to it from the application.

```
socat openssl-listen:443,reuseaddr,cert=./fake.pem echo
```

The packets I capture in Wireshark are

```
Client (C) -> Server(S): SYN
S->C: SYN-ACK
C->S: ACK
C->S: sClient Hello
S->C: ACK
S->C: Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
C->S: Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
S->C: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: handshake Failure)
S->C: RST ACK`
```

I thought that socat only checks against the option `cafile` (at least that's what it says in the manpage). Does it perform additional checks I could disable?

Could there be other good reasons why the server side would complain besides not a valid certificate from the client?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was the `certificate request` part. The client application didn't send any certificate and if option `verify=0` is added to the socat listener it works fine. `verify` is set to True by default.